# how to split the view into halves and addid a scroll view on each half of the view?

Tags: ios, pdf

I have to divide the view int two,on the first half i have to add a scroll view(i.e to call a specific method in scroll view for setting a page) and on the second half i have to add another scroll view.I have to do this programmatically.Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily split a UIView into two. 
If I understand you right I would do something like this

```
UIScrollView scroller1  = [UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, splittedView.frame.size.width /2, splittedView.frame.size.height) ];
UIScrollView scroller2  = [UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(splittedView.frame.size.width /2,0, splittedView.frame.size.width /2, splittedView.frame.size.height) ];

[splittedView addSubView: scroller1]; 
[splittedView addSubView: scroller2];
```

Now you have a view with two scrollviews on it. And every scrollview has half the size of your main view.

Comment: Yes,you are right.Your answer is absolutely correct.After setting the frame,I have to call a function in the scroll view to set the page. PDFScrollView scrollView= [[PDFScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.view.frame.size.width /2, self.view.frame.size.height) ];                         [(PDFScrollView *)self.view setPDFPage:PDFPage]; Is this correct?

Comment: I think you shouldn't set something like this [(PDFScrollView *)self.view setPDFPage:PDFPage]; 
But I'm not 100% sure because I don't know your PDFScrollView class

I would add it as a subview